# Why do partial derivatives need to be continuous in order for the function to be differentiable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Why it's not enough for the partial derivatives to exist for implying differentiability of the function? 
Why is the continuity of the partial derivatives needed?

Comment: It not neede: it is only a sufficient condition for a function to be differentiable.

Comment: To answer your first question: because they're partial, i.e., derivatives in very special directions.

Comment: @Bernard So what are the conditions for a function to be differentiable at some point?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Well yes, but they can exist in all directions and it still doesn't mean that the function is differentiable at that point. please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I only know the definition:a function defined on an open set of a normed space $f$ is differentiable at some point $a$ of its domain if there exists a continuous  linear map $L$ on the space such that $$f(a+h)=f(a)+L(h)+o(\lVert h\rVert).$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** :

consider $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$,  $f(0,0) = 0$

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question: because they're partial, i.e., derivatives in very special directions.  Imagine, for example, a surface which is generated by a ray parallel to the $x$-$y$-axis that is rotating in a way that for the first quarter of its rotation it raises by $1$, for the next quarter it lowers by $1$, then lowers $1$ again and in its last quarter it raises again by $1$.